# Category links to stay on the same page

Tags: categories, links

Is it possible to use Category links that don't link to a different URL, but instead to a different part of a page.  So for example, I want the Category link that is generated to produce:

```
<a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
```

instead of:

```
<a href="section1">Section 1</a>
```

The "#" sign disappears when I try to change the "Category URL Title" field.

Answer (score 2):

Of course!

The `path` variable can be put aside and you can create the links by your own. Just code the href attribute as you need.

Some samples:

```
<a href="{path='channel/index'}">{category_name}</a>
<a href="#{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a>
```